# vim freezes in D state on quit but nano works fine

Tags: vim

On ubuntu 14.04, on quitting from vim, it consistently freezes in D state, whether or not I make any changes or save. Opening the same file with less or nano works perfectly fine, so I don't think it is a disc/io issue.

This just suddenly randomly started happening, and I can't think of a possible cause. I also haven't edited my vimrc in a very long time so it's probably not that. Any ideas on how to debug is appreciated.

Comment: Try resetting vim by typing - `mv ~/.vim ~/.vim.bak && mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc.bak`. Check if the problem persists.

Comment: Tried reinstalling vim ?

Comment: okay, I guess it is something in my vimrc even though it's been working fine all this time. Thanks, I'll update this when I find out exactly what it is.

Comment: The problem seems to be with source /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/plugin/powerline.vim.